# angularjs select2 selected value is not shown in the field

Tags: angularjs, jquery-select2, angularjs-select2

I am using angularjs with select2 plugin.

When I edit an item that has a property where I can set it from a drop down, the current selected value is selected/highlighted in the drop-down but is not visible. I have to actually click the drop-down to see the actual option selected. Basically at first the field is empty ...

Like this:

[image]

As you can see the field is empty but if you click it then you see that Arizona is selected. How can I show Arizona right in the drop down without having to click it?

And this is how I bind it to the element.

```
  <select data-custom-select class="form-control" data-ng-model="newType.Type" data-ng-options="t for t in definitions.Types"></select>
```

`data-custom-select` is a directive that allows me to apply `select2()` on the element:

```
 directive('customSelect', [function () {
    var link = function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.select2();
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: link
    };
}])
```

The model:

```
$scope.newType = {
    Type: 'Type 1'
}

$scope.definitions ={
    "Definitions": [{
        "Id": "1",
        "Name": "Name 1"        
    }, {
       "Id": "2",
        "Name": "Name 2" 
    }],
    "Types": ["Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 3"]
};
```

Comment: Please add relevant code or create a demo on a page like [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/?html,js,output).

Comment: I added the needed information. The screenshot is not relevant to the code but just to show the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try not to mix up `jQuery` plugins and `angularjs`. There's an `angularjs` module for `Select2` here: [angular-ui/ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select)

Example: http://jsbin.com/nojewamivu/1/edit?html,js,output